# Why is setting password_digest working in my Rails console but not via controller logic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm practicing some Rails authentication from scratch (sans Devise gem), but having a few issues for some reason implementing `ActiveModel::SecurePassword`. If I go into console I'm able to create a fresh user, see all the validations enforced, and if I save a new user (e.g, `user.save`), I see `password_digest` successfully set.

However, if I create a new User ***via my user registration form***, my `password_digest` is `nil` every time. Anyone know why? I know for sure my params are being received, as I can print them before saving and see them.

For context, here's what I've tried:

- Added `ActiveModel::SecurePassword` to my user model
- Enabled `bcrypt` gem and ran `bundle install`
- If I go into `irb`, I'm able to generate a new instance fine like so and see the `password_digest`:

```rb
3.2.1 :137 > new_user = User.new(first_name: "test", last_name: "tester", email: "foo@bar.com", password: "123123123")
 => #<User:0x0000000107c5bf40 id: nil, first_name: "test", last_name: "tester", email: "foo@bar.com", password: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
3.2.1 :138 > new_user.save
  TRANSACTION (0.7ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists? (0.8ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "foo@bar.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Create (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("first_name", "last_name", "email", "password", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["first_name", "test"], ["last_name", "tester"], ["email", "foo@bar.com"], ["password", "[FILTERED]"], ["created_at", "2023-03-07 03:36:07.501992"], ["updated_at", "2023-03-07 03:36:07.501992"]]
  TRANSACTION (1.3ms)  COMMIT
 => true
3.2.1 :139 > new_user.password_digest
 => "$2a$12$aIcAuAdSnJhrLw0bWHTh1OgTTmUioB2ra3h12cFNs/IwnJdyRYJEW"
# NOTE:^ Successfully encrypts the password field via Bcrypt
```

However, if I run through my registration form, all the params are correct, I get `nil` for this field. Here's an `irb` printout from latest user created from registration form:

```rb
3.2.1 :140 > latest_user = User.last
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<User:0x0000000107d75ca0 id: 27, first_name: "Allday", last_name: "Everyday", email: "allday@everyday.com", password: nil, created_at: Tue, 07 Mar 2023 03:39:13.986217000 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 07 Mar 2023 03:39:13.986217000 UTC +00:00>
3.2.1 :141 > latest_user.password_digest
 => nil
# NOTE: digest is `nil`!
```

---

For reference, here's my current User model and my `user_controller.rb` logic:

## `user.rb`

```rb
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id              :bigint           not null, primary key
#  email           :string
#  first_name      :string
#  last_name       :string
#  password        :string
#  password_digest :string
#  created_at      :datetime         not null
#  updated_at      :datetime         not null
#
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include ActiveModel::SecurePassword
  has_secure_password
  has_secure_password :recovery_password, validations: false
  
  before_save :downcase_email

  validates :email, format: {with: URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP}, uniqueness: true, presence: true
  validates :first_name, length: {minimum: 2, maximum: 100}, presence: true
  validates :last_name, length: {minimum: 2, maximum: 100}, presence: true
  validates :password, length: {minimum: 8, maximum: 25}, presence: true

  attr_accessor :password_digest, :recovery_password_digest

  private
  def downcase_email
    self.email = email.downcase
  end
end
```

And here's my controller logic:

## `user_controller.rb`

```rb
class UserController < ApplicationController
  # post '/user/register'
  def create
    user = User.new(user_params)
    begin
      user.save!
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      return render json: {success: true, status: 200}
    rescue => exception
      return render json: {success: false, status: 422, error: exception.message}
    end
  end

  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

Anyone see anything I'm doing that's wrong or have any suggestions on why `password_digest` might be null when creating a User via controller method logic? Thanks so much for all of your time--been stumped on this one!

Comment: Did you check the queries running from console and from controller same?

Comment: And why are you using attr_accessor :password_digest ? It's already present in database right? model should pick it directly?

Comment: Thank you @Gagan Gupta! For context, I was following a long with a rails guide [example](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_asics.html#examples) and I should have understood what `attr_accessor` is doing--read up and understand now. Thank you for taking the time to help me out!

Comment: Glad that your issue is now resolved! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line from your `app/models/user.rb`

```
attr_accessor :password_digest, :recovery_password_digest
```

Because the getter and setter methods created by `attr_accessor` will override the methods that Ruby on Rails will create automatically for columns found in the database.

Comment: Thank you--this did the trick!  I had been following along with some [example code](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_basics.html#examples) in one of the ruby guides and should have been more critical (and since your feedback have read up)! Thank you and completely makes sense--sincerely thanks for taking the time to help me out!